# How to plot data with Axes3D in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot data by using Axes3D of python. This is my code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 192, 74]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
z =  [1455, 1219, 1240, 1338, 1276, 1298, 1292, 1157, 486, 1388]
dx = np.ones(10)
dy = np.ones(10)
dz = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]


fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color='#00ceaa')
ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(x)
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(y)
ax.set_title("Data Analysis ")
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')


plt.show()
```

[image]

My problem is that I expect to have a large bars that must look like histogram. But I don't have that result, That means it looks like this:

[image: mat]

What must I change in my code to have a figure like the second figure please?

Comment: Have you tried to adapt the [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/hist3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-hist3d-py)? If yes, why did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't currently get transparent bars in any matplotlib version >=2 ([Issue #10237](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10237)).

Apart, the problem is that you got the role of x,y,z and dx, dy, dz wrong somehow. I suppose you meant something like

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 192, 74]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
z =  np.zeros(10)
dx = np.ones(10)*10
dy = np.ones(10)
dz = [1455, 1219, 1240, 1338, 1276, 1298, 1292, 1157, 486, 1388]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
bar3d = ax.bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color='C0')

ax.set_title("Data Analysis ")
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

[image]